# WebKit FileNotFoundException Error

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-errors, filenotfoundexception

I just downloaded [WebKit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/), and put the dll in, and put a WebKitBrowser on my `Form`, and now I'm getting this error:
[image: Error]

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? This is what I have in my references:
[image: References]

I have tried searching google for a answer to my problem, but none of them helped me.

I have tried to use fuslogvw.exe, but can't access it.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You have all the dependecies of WebKit in the Debug folder and Realase folder?

Comment: I have my dll's in the bin folder of my solution.

Comment: Make sure that you have CopyLocal set to `true` for the WebKit dlls.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that what I needed to do was copy the dll's for `WebKitBrowser` and paste them into

```
bin/Debug
```

and

```
bin/Release
```

Hopefully that will help anyone else looking for how to fix it!

Comment: Best would be to the file(dll) to your project and change the properties to 'copy to output directory'.

Comment: Would probably work. I have the dll's in my folders now, so I don't need that anymore. :)

Comment: I would do it (takes 20sec). It helps if someone else is going to use your code, or you are continuing it later on.